# Select child elements when parent ID is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, select

I made a multi-choice select box. I used select2.

I want all child elements to be selected when Parent is selected.

For example, when ex1 is selected, every element should be selected.

When ex2 is selected, 4,5,7,8,9 and itself should be selected.

I tried to create a loop for this, but it just didn't make sense because there could be too many elements under each other.

[image: Visualisation of tree]

jsfiddle link here https://jsfiddle.net/ph40eomt/2/

Thanks for the help in advance.

```js
$('.js-select2-custom').select2({
  "minimumResultsForSearch": "Infinity",
  "singleMultiple": true,
})

function selectNumber() {
  let select = $('.js-select2-custom')
  select.next('span.select2').find('ul').html(function() {
    let count = select.select2('data').length
    return "<li style='font-size: 14px;line-height: 26px;color: black;'>" + count + " units Selected" + "</li>"
  })
}

selectNumber()

$('.js-select2-custom').on('select2:close', function() {
  let select = $(this)
  $(this).next('span.select2').find('ul').html(function() {
    let count = select.select2('data').length
    return "<li style='font-size: 14px;line-height: 26px;color: black;'>" + count + " units Selected" + "</li>"
  })
})

$('.js-select2-custom').on('select2:select', function(e) {
  var data = e.params.data;
  var userArrOptions = $("select[name='organizationUnitSelect'] option")

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < userArrOptions.length; i++) {

    var childId = $(userArrOptions[i]).attr("data-parent-id")
    var selectedChildId = []

    if (data.id == childId) {
      var selectedOption = $('.js-select2-custom option[data-parent-id=' + childId + ']')
      selectedOption.prop('selected', true);

    }
  }

  $('.js-select2-custom').select2({
    "minimumResultsForSearch": "Infinity",
    "singleMultiple": true,
  })

  selectNumber()

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select class="js-select2-custom form-control" multiple name="organizationUnitSelect">
    <option class="options" value="1" data-parent-id="">ex1</option>
    <option class="options" value="2" data-parent-id="1">ex2</option>
    <option class="options" value="3" data-parent-id="1">ex3</option>
    <option class="options" value="4" data-parent-id="2">ex4</option>
    <option class="options" value="5" data-parent-id="2">ex5</option>
    <option class="options" value="6" data-parent-id="3">ex6</option>
    <option class="options" value="7" data-parent-id="4">ex7</option>
    <option class="options" value="8" data-parent-id="4">ex8</option>
    <option class="options" value="9" data-parent-id="7">ex9</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it something like this you want https://jsfiddle.net/te7oLh3x/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yes, thank you.

Comment: I've edited your question to create a runnable snippet from your code; please could you add in a link to the `select2` plugin so that it can reproduce your problem?

Comment: how you build your binary tree?